# Change uppercase "Edited by" to lowercase "edited by" using biblatex.sty

Tags: biblatex

My codes are:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[american]{babel}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[maxbibnames=99,%style=numeric,
style=ext-numeric,%
citestyle=numeric,sorting=nyt,sortcites=true,autopunct=true,autolang=hyphen,hyperref=true,abbreviate=false,backref=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{wertheimer1938,
  author      = {Wertheimer, Max},
  title       = {Gestalt theory},
  editor      = {Willis D. Ellis},
  booktitle   = {A Source Book of Gestalt Psychology},
  publisher   = {London: Kegan Paul, Trench, Trubner},
  year        = {1938},
  pages       = {1--11},
}

@incollection{bulthoff1996bayesian,
  title={Bayesian Decision Theory and Psychophysics},
  author={Bulthoff, Heinrich H.},
  booktitle={Perception as Bayesian Inference},
  editor={David C. Knill and Whitman Richards},
  pages={123--162},
  publisher={Cambridge: Cambridge University Press},
  year={1996}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} 

\begin{document}
\renewbibmacro*{in:}{%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \ifentrytype{incollection}
    {}
    {\printtext{%
       \bibstring{In}\intitlepunct}}}


\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Output as:

[image]

Kindly advise how to meet the required output, please

I've made `Edited by` into lowercase `edited by` after tried with the below tag:

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  byeditor = {\lowercase{edited by}},%
  byeditor = {\lowercase{edited by}},%
}
```

But not able to change the `period` to `comma`, before `edited by`, please advise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have to redefine the `byeditor+others` macro to set the punctuation to a comma rather than the default period.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{wertheimer1938,
  author      = {Wertheimer, Max},
  title       = {Gestalt theory},
  editor      = {Willis D. Ellis},
  booktitle   = {A Source Book of Gestalt Psychology},
  publisher   = {London: Kegan Paul, Trench, Trubner},
  year        = {1938},
  pages       = {1--11},
}

@incollection{bulthoff1996bayesian,
  title={Bayesian Decision Theory and Psychophysics},
  author={Bulthoff, Heinrich H.},
  booktitle={Perception as Bayesian Inference},
  editor={David C. Knill and Whitman Richards},
  pages={123--162},
  publisher={Cambridge: Cambridge University Press},
  year={1996}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[style=ext-numeric,abbreviate=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} 

\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{byeditor+othersstrg}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
     \clearname{editor}%
     \setunit{\addcomma\space}}
  \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}

\renewbibmacro*{in:}{%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \ifentrytype{incollection}
    {}
    {\printtext{\bibstring{In}\intitlepunct}}}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works perfect

Comment: New Year wishes to you and your family too